# C - How do I free memory that is allocated in other functions?

Tags: c, function, malloc, external, free

Here's my main:

```
int main()
{
   int  i;
   int *a = readData(N);
   int *f = frequency(a, N, MAX);
   int c = 0;

   printf("%9s %9s\n", "Number", "Frequency");
   for( i = 0; i <= MAX; i ++)
   {  
      c += f[i];
      printf("%9d %9d\n", i, f[i]); 
   }

   printf("total frequency for all words: %d\n", c);
   free(f);
   free(a);
   printf("All memory freed!\n");

   return(0);
}
```

and here is the first supporting function

```
int * readData(int size)
{
    int i, *array = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    for(i =0; i<N;i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);

    return array;
}
```

and the second supporting function

```
int * frequency(int *input, int size, int max)
{
    int i, x;
    int *farray = malloc(max+1*sizeof(int));    
    for(i = 0; i<=max;i++)
        farray[i]=0;

    for(i = 0; i<1099; i++)
    {   
        x = input[i];
        farray[x]++;
    }

    return farray;
}
```

Everything works great! When I run it through valgrind, it tells me that all my memory was freed. But, when I run the program normally, it crashes at the end with a core dump when I free the allocated memory. Why? Thanks in advance! I'm new at C.

Comment: What's `N`? What's `MAX`? The loop with the hardcoded limit of `i < 1099` looks suspicious, will the "array" `input` contain `1099` entries? Why are you passing in the `size` parameter if you don't use it?

Comment: The hardcoded entry was there for debugging, but thank you for pointing that out as I meant to change it back to 'size'.

Answer (score 4):

It's true that all the memory is freed, but the size you allocated is not correct.

```
int *farray = malloc(max+1*sizeof(int));
```

Here, the size is `max` plus one `sizeof(int))`, it should be:

```
int *farray = malloc((max+1)*sizeof(int));
```